# Postgresql 9.1 - Kali Linux

Tags: kali-linux, postgresql, backtrack, nmap, metasploit

I started to read this book : http://www.amazon.fr/Metasploit-The-Penetration-Testers-Guide/dp/159327288X

And I have some trouble with `postgresql 9.1` (in Kali Linux).

When I start `msfconsole`, I first have this message :

> Failed to connect to the database: could not connect to server: Connection refused
>       Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
>   could not connect to server: Connection refused
>       Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
>       TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

And then `msfconsole` starts normally.

After that, I tried to connect to `postgresql`, using the credentials I've found in `/opt/metasploit/apps/pro/ui/config/database.yml`

But it doesn't work, because **authentication failed**.

Comment: is your database running on your system? `service postgres start`. Source is here https://community.rapid7.com/thread/4246

Comment: Thank you for the answer.

I'm gonna check that this evening because i'm not currently in front of my laptop.